# No package php-oci8 available. CentOS 7

Tags: php, centos, php-7, oci8, php-7.3

I intend to install `oci8` for `PHP 7.3.4` on a CentOS 7 with a lot of restrictions. For example I have no `pecl` etc. I also prefer to run via standard packages rather than strange repositories from fancy but none official URLs.

Here is what I get:

```
# yum install php-oci8

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, tmprepo
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.gbnetwork.my
 * epel: epel.mirror.angkasa.id
 * extras: centos.gbnetwork.my
 * updates: centos.gbnetwork.my
No package php-oci8 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

.

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi-php73 install php-oci8

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, tmprepo


Error getting repository data for remi-php73, repository not found
```

What is the solution?

Comment: "remi" repository need to be added to system before using it.
See the wizard instructions: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: Also see howto for oracle https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2020/05/18/Installation-of-Oracle-extensions-for-PHP